# How can I make a custom dynamic footer in TCPDF with data taken from a database?

Tags: tcpdf

I would like to make a dynamic footer containing data taken from a database.
How to extend TCPDF class to put those data in?

```
// my DB stuff here
$datafromdb = getDataFromDB();

 class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    // Page footer
    public function Footer() {
        // Position at 10 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-10);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('dejavusans', 'I', 8);
        $foot = $datafromdb.'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages();

        $this->MultiCell(0, 10, $foot, 0, 'C');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add a __construct method to pass your data.
try this :

```
// my DB stuff here
$datafromdb = getDataFromDB();

class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    private $datafromdb ;//<-- to save your data

    function __construct( $datafromdb , $orientation, $unit, $format ) 
    {
        parent::__construct( $orientation, $unit, $format, true, 'UTF-8', false );

        $this->datafromdb = $datafromdb ;
        //...
    }
    // Page footer
    public function Footer() {
        // Position at 10 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-10);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('dejavusans', 'I', 8);
        $foot = $this->datafromdb.'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages();

        $this->MultiCell(0, 10, $foot, 0, 'C');
    }
}
```