# Extending Footer Class in TCPDF to add a url from another function

Tags: php, class, tcpdf

I want to add a url generated from another function in TCPDF's footer.

[tcpdf edit footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824423/tcpdf-edit-footer)

Similar to that, but with a variable from a function, let's call it:

```
function function_name() {
$variable = 'urlvalue';
}
```

How would I get this information ($variable) into the TCPDF footer? Would I have to make the variable global? Could I pass it in some manner?

Comment: I'm instantiating an extended class inside my function. I want to pass a variable to this extended class.

Comment: you can try [How can I make a custom dynamic footer in TCPDF with data taken from a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20479212/2310786) solution.   
change DB stuff with your URL stuff.